# How can I properly align two minipages under a table?

Tags: positioning

I have a table, and I want to put two legends underneath. These are minipages (I found no other way of getting this done), but I am having a hard time aligning them in the center of the page and on the same height. vspace and hspace do not move the minipage in question up or down (or left or right), but make things jump around the page unpredictably. How can I align them properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\def\hbar#1#2{%%
   {\color{#2}\rule{4mm}{#1mm}}}
\def\legbox#1#2{%%
   {\color{#1}\rule{4mm}{4mm}} \hspace{0.4mm}#2 \hspace{3mm}\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \vspace*{-4.0cm}
  \hspace*{-4.2cm}
  \centering
  {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{50pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{lllccl}
  \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline
  \hline
    Item Description Name & Most Recent Update & State District & Governmental Body & Bars & More bars \\
    \hline
      Item 1 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
      \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
      \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
      \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}    \\   
      Item 2 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
      \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
      \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
      \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}      \\ 
      Item 3 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
      \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
      \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
      \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}       \\
      Item 4 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
      \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
      \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
      \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}       \\
      Item 5 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
      \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
      \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
      \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}       \\
  \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{Here goes a table caption to describe the table}
\hspace{-10cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\vspace{1cm}
 \textbf{Legend 1} \\
\legbox{black}{Long Label 1}
\legbox{blue}{Label 2}
\legbox{black}{Long Label 3}
\legbox{blue}{Label 4}
\legbox{black}{Long Label 5}
\legbox{blue}{Label 6}
\legbox{black}{Long Label 7}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\hspace{8cm}
\vspace{-4.7cm}
\\\textbf{Legend 2} \\

\legbox{blue}{Another label}
\legbox{black}{Mini}
\legbox{green}{A pretty long label}
\legbox{green}{A label}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: Current layout]

And here is how I would like it to look (line only for illustrative purposes):

[image: Preferred layout]

Comment: It is pretty difficult to help you without some kind of a MWE that illustrates the issue you want resolved.  Please post a MWE.

Comment: You can use `\hspace*` or `\vspace*` to horizontal/vertical adjustments. There's also `\raisebox` which moves content up/down. In general, it really depends on the type of content and where they are located in order to answer your question accurately.

Comment: I thought of leaving it generic because I often encounter this same issue. Rather than solving it for one specific situation, are there general recommendations with regards to placement of objects (as mentioned in the text, this regards tables, figures, and other boxes)? Or is a specific MWE necessary?

Comment: @user: Then your answer may very well lie in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD), since they cover general placement options...

Comment: One other reason for the MWE is that it sounds very fishy that you'd need to move tables and so forth "very often" "less than 1 cm" (especially with regard to moving them left or right).  It might well be that your ad hoc moves are in fact but compensation for other coding practices that are introducing the problem in the first place.

Comment: Copy that - I will reform this question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're hoping for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\def\hbar#1#2{%%
   {\color{#2}\rule{4mm}{#1mm}}}
\def\legbox#1#2{%%
   {\color{#1}\rule{4mm}{4mm}} \hspace{0.4mm}#2 \hspace{3mm}\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]
  {%%
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{50pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{lllccl}
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline
    \hline
      Item Description Name & Most Recent Update & State District & Governmental Body & Bars & More bars \\
      \hline
        Item 1 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
        \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
        \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
        \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}    \\   
        Item 2 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
        \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
        \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
        \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}      \\ 
        Item 3 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
        \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
        \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
        \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}       \\
        Item 4 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
        \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
        \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
        \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}       \\
        Item 5 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
        \hbar{14}{green} \hbar{20}{green} \hbar{10}{green} \hbar{15}{red}
        \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red} \hbar{10}{red}  &
        \hbar{15}{red} \hbar{19}{red} \hbar{6}{red}       \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{Here goes a table caption to describe the table}
  \vspace{2ex}\par
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    {\centering\textbf{Legend 1}}%%

    \legbox{black}{Long Label 1}
    \legbox{blue}{Label 2}
    \legbox{black}{Long Label 3}
    \legbox{blue}{Label 4}
    \legbox{black}{Long Label 5}
    \legbox{blue}{Label 6}
    \legbox{black}{Long Label 7}
  \end{minipage}%%
  \hspace{\fill}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
    {\centering\textbf{Legend 2}}%%

    \legbox{blue}{Another label}
    \legbox{black}{Mini}
    \legbox{green}{A pretty long label}
    \legbox{green}{A label}
  \end{minipage}%%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm able to eliminate most of your `\hspace` and `\vspace` commands.

Your table is larger than the geometry of the page allows.  You can center it on the page by putting its body in a `\makebox` of `0pt` width.  Essentially, I replace your code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \vspace*{-4.0cm}
  \hspace*{-4.2cm}
  \centering
  {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{50pt}%
```

with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]
  {%%
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{50pt}%
```

You're also using `\hspace` and `\vspace` a lot with your legends in a manner that seems unnecessary.  Here are some adjustments that I made:

- After `\caption` I added a vertical space to better control the space between the caption and legends instead of adding the vertical space within the `minipage`s.
- Within the `minipage`s for the legend, I'm a bit uncertain what you're trying to accomplish with your `\hspace` and `\vspace` commands.  It seems that you can completely avoid these by making a paragraph break between the legend title and body and centering the title.

Answer (score 1):

The table, as is, cannot fit any reasonable page width, so I've shrunk it.

For the legend, just use a couple of `tabular`.

I also changed your `\def` into `\newcommand` and `\hbar` into `\HBar` not to conflict with an already existing command. Be *very* careful with `\def`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand\HBar[2]{%%
   {\color{#2}\rule{3mm}{#1mm}}%
}
\newcommand\legbox[2]{%%
   {\color{#1}\rule{4mm}{4mm}}\hspace{0.4mm}#2\hspace{3mm}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begingroup\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2.8pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllccc@{}}
\toprule
\makecell{Item \\ Description \\ Name} &
  \makecell{Most Recent \\ Update} &
  \makecell{State \\ District} &
  \makecell{Governmental \\ Body} &
  Bars &
  More bars \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
Item 1 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
\HBar{14}{green} \HBar{20}{green} \HBar{10}{green} \HBar{15}{red}
\HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red} \HBar{10}{red}  &
\HBar{15}{red} \HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red}    \\
\addlinespace
Item 2 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
\HBar{14}{green} \HBar{20}{green} \HBar{10}{green} \HBar{15}{red}
\HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red} \HBar{10}{red}  &
\HBar{15}{red} \HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red}      \\ 
\addlinespace
Item 3 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
\HBar{14}{green} \HBar{20}{green} \HBar{10}{green} \HBar{15}{red}
\HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red} \HBar{10}{red}  &
\HBar{15}{red} \HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red}       \\
\addlinespace
Item 4 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
\HBar{14}{green} \HBar{20}{green} \HBar{10}{green} \HBar{15}{red}
\HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red} \HBar{10}{red}  &
\HBar{15}{red} \HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red}       \\
\addlinespace
Item 5 & Jan 1, 2010 & District 1 & GB 3 &
\HBar{14}{green} \HBar{20}{green} \HBar{10}{green} \HBar{15}{red}
\HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red} \HBar{10}{red}  &
\HBar{15}{red} \HBar{19}{red} \HBar{6}{red}       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\caption{Here goes a table caption to describe the table}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Legend 1}} \\
\legbox{black}{Long Label 1} \\
\legbox{blue}{Label 2} \\
\legbox{black}{Long Label 3} \\
\legbox{blue}{Label 4} \\
\legbox{black}{Long Label 5} \\
\legbox{blue}{Label 6} \\
\legbox{black}{Long Label 7} \\
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Legend 2}} \\
\legbox{blue}{Another label} \\
\legbox{black}{Mini} \\
\legbox{green}{A pretty long label} \\
\legbox{green}{A label} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]